# Give an example of a non-Lebesgue measurable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that $|f|$ is a measurable function and ...

Tags: measure-theory

> Give an example of a non-Lebesgue measurable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that $|f|$ is a measurable function and $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is a measurable set for each $a \in \mathbb R$.

Can anyone please help show me how I can construct such an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E \subset [0,1]$ be any non-measurable set (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) for example). Define $f$ as follows:

- $f(x) = x$ if $x \in E$
- $f(x) = -x$ if $x \in [0,1] \setminus E $
- Zero otherwise

Try to prove that this is a bona fide example.

Comment: Thank you! :). This is an excellent example and very easy to verify :). Thanks so much for this :)